# How to provide test data to a locustfile in Python for load testing

Tags: python, api, testing, load, locust

I have built an API using flask and want to do load testing using locust.
Can anyone help me how to create it and do a load testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the correct result I have come up with the way how you will pass your input to the flask API at the time of load testing.

**Load test for the text classification API**

```py
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
import os
import random
TEST_DATA_PATH = 'load_test_data.txt' 

def load_test_sentences():  
   sent = []  
   with open(TEST_DATA_PATH, 'rb') as fp:
     for row in fp:  
       row = row.strip()   
       sent.append(row)  
   return sent

class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.sent=load_test_sentences()

    @task(1)
    def about(self):
        for ut in self.sent:
            self.client.get("/entity-extractor/location?q={}".format(ut.decode("utf-8")),name='Text Classification') 

class MyLocust(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    host = "http://0.0.0.0:8000"
    min_wait = 5000
    max_wait = 15000
    def __init__(self):
        print('loaded %s sentences' %len(load_test_sentences()))
        super(MyLocust, self).__init__()
```